# How do I identify the level of a field in copybook using JRecord in Java?

Tags: java, cobol, ebcdic, copybook, jrecord

I am trying to read a EBCDIC file and convert it to ASCII format in Java, with a help of copybook. I am using JRecord to read the copybook. So now, how do I get the field level from the copybook using JRecord?

Edit 1:

Kindly excuse me for a vague question. I have no experience in mainframe or cobol. I am adding few more details if it could help.

My source file contains multiple transaction details. The copybook contains the information on the transaction and the fields relating to that particular transaction.

I have to split the each transaction and its fields to a separate file(containing one transaction and respective fields).

[CopyBook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZZF9.png)

In attached copybook, the field in line 1 can have values from line 2 to line 4. If the EXTRA-TYPE is 01, then I have to read fields in line 6 to line 11. Similarly, if the EXTRA-TYPE is 02, then I have to read fields in line 12 to line 16. 
I am trying to split the Transaction type and its respective fields dynamically.
(I need to get the start and end position of the fields with respect to the transaction type in line 1)How do I achieve this in Java?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Priya welcome to stackoverflow. It is generally expected people to `make an effort` and `show` what they have tried. This saves people answering the question from trying the same thing. Also questions need to be more `precise` and `direct` on what you are trying to do. I do not understand why you need Cobol Level numbers if you are converting the file ascii. I have provided a generic answer covering several possibilities.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin. I have updated my question with actual requirement. Give me your suggestions. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to get the Field Level ???. To convert a file to ascii you do not need the Field Level.

---

#### Utility Conversion Program

To Convert a **Cobol** File to **ascii** you can use one of the utility programs:

- [Cobol2Csv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/) sub-project - converts a Cobol data file to a Csv file
- [Cobol2Xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltoxml/) sub-project - converts a Cobol data file to a Xml file
- [Cobol2Json](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/files/jrecord/Version_0.81.4) json utiltiy

### Java processing of a Cobol file

If you want to do some processing on the File, you can use the **Generate**
function of the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) to generate sample [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) code from the Cobol copybook.

#### Code generated with standard template

If you use the **standard** template, the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) will generate code like:

```
    AbstractLine line;
    int lineNum = 0;

    try {
        ICobolIOBuilder iob = JRecordInterface1.COBOL
                                   .newIOBuilder(copybookName)
                                       .setFont("cp037")
                                       .setFileOrganization(Constants.IO_FIXED_LENGTH)
                                       .setSplitCopybook(CopybookLoader.SPLIT_NONE)
                                   ;  


        FieldNamesDtar020.RecordDtar020 rDtar020 = FieldNamesDtar020.RECORD_DTAR020;
        AbstractLineReader reader = iob.newReader(dataFile);
        while ((line = reader.read()) != null) {
            lineNum += 1;
            System.out.println(
                          line.getFieldValue(rDtar020.keycodeNo).asString()
                  + " " + line.getFieldValue(rDtar020.storeNo).asString()
                  + " " + line.getFieldValue(rDtar020.date).asString()
                  + " " + line.getFieldValue(rDtar020.deptNo).asString()
                  + " " + line.getFieldValue(rDtar020.qtySold).asString()
                  + " " + line.getFieldValue(rDtar020.salePrice).asString()
               );
        }

        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("~~> " + lineNum + " " + e);
        System.out.println();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

#### Code generated with lineWrapper template

```
  AbstractLine line;
    int lineNum = 0;

    try {
        ICobolIOBuilder iob = JRecordInterface1.COBOL
                                   .newIOBuilder(copybookName)
                                       .setFont("cp037")
                                       .setFileOrganization(Constants.IO_FIXED_LENGTH)
                                       .setSplitCopybook(CopybookLoader.SPLIT_NONE)
                                   ;  


       LineDtar020JR lineDtar020JR = new LineDtar020JR();


       AbstractLineReader reader = iob.newReader(dataFile);
       while ((line = reader.read()) != null) {
           lineNum += 1;
           lineDtar020JR.setLine(line);
           System.out.println(
                          lineDtar020JR.getKeycodeNo() 
                  + " " + lineDtar020JR.getStoreNo() 
                  + " " + lineDtar020JR.getDate() 
                  + " " + lineDtar020JR.getDeptNo() 
                  + " " + lineDtar020JR.getQtySold() 
                  + " " + lineDtar020JR.getSalePrice() 
               );
        }

        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("~~> " + lineNum + " " + e);
        System.out.println();

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

---

### Generic Cobol processing

If you want to do more generic processing you can use a **fieldIterator**:

```
FieldIterator fieldIterator = line.getFieldIterator("Record-Name");
```

---

#### JRecord Examples

In the latest release of [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) **0.81.4** there are examples in the **Source/JRecord_IO_Builder_Examples/src** directory

---

### Tree processing

If you need to access level numbers with JRecord, use  **CobolSchemaReader.newCobolSchemaReader(...)** interface.

Also you could look at the code for [Cobol2Xml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltoxml/) sub-project. It does `tree` processing by extending **CobolSchemaReader**

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of
http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html or https://www.mikeash.com/getting_answers.html about asking questions

But any way:

#### Using the Code Generation

- Download the Recordeditor from https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/files/Test/Version_0.98.3/ the USB version does not need to be installed - just unzip it
- Start the RecordEditor and select the generate option

[image]

- Enter the Cobol Copybook, Sample cobol file (if you hava one). You will
  **probably** be able to use the *Split Copybook* **On Redefines** option

[image]

- On the **Records** panel, enter **DA147-EXTRA-TYPE** in the *Record Type* field

[image]

- Press the **Generate Code** button. On the next screen you can select the *template*. The **Standard** template is a good starting point

[image]

- Press the **Generate** code button, The program should generate some sample code like:

  ```
      ICobolIOBuilder iob = JRecordInterface1.COBOL
                                 .newIOBuilder(copybookName)
                                     .setFileOrganization(Constants.IO_BIN_TEXT)
                                     .setSplitCopybook(CopybookLoader.SPLIT_REDEFINE)
                                 ;  


      FieldNamesAmspodownloadRedef1.RecordPoHeaderRecord rPoHeaderRecord = FieldNamesAmspodownloadRedef1.RECORD_PO_HEADER_RECORD;
      FieldNamesAmspodownloadRedef1.RecordProductRecord rProductRecord = FieldNamesAmspodownloadRedef1.RECORD_PRODUCT_RECORD;
      FieldNamesAmspodownloadRedef1.RecordLocationRecord rLocationRecord = FieldNamesAmspodownloadRedef1.RECORD_LOCATION_RECORD;
      AbstractLineReader reader = iob.newReader(dataFile);
      while ((line = reader.read()) != null) {
          lineNum += 1;
          if (
             "H1".equals(line.getFieldValue(rPoHeaderRecord.recordType).asString())
          )  {

             System.out.println(
                        line.getFieldValue(rPoHeaderRecord.recordType).asString()
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rPoHeaderRecord.sequenceNumber).asString()
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rPoHeaderRecord.vendor).asString()
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rPoHeaderRecord.po).asString()
                  ....
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rPoHeaderRecord.cancelByDate).asString()
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rPoHeaderRecord.ediType).asString()
             );
          }
          if (
             "D1".equals(line.getFieldValue(rProductRecord.recordType).asString())
          )  {

             System.out.println(
                        line.getFieldValue(rProductRecord.recordType).asString()
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rProductRecord.packQty).asString()
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rProductRecord.packCost).asString()
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rProductRecord.apn).asString()
                + " " + 
                    .....
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rProductRecord.productName).asString()
             );
          }
          if (
             "S1".equals(line.getFieldValue(rLocationRecord.recordType).asString())
          )  {

             System.out.println(
                        line.getFieldValue(rLocationRecord.recordType).asString()
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rLocationRecord.dcNumbe.get(0)).asString()
                + " " + line.getFieldValue(rLocationRecord.packQuantit.get(0)).asString()
             );
          }
  ```