# Mainframe comp-3 field reading using JRecord

Tags: java, mainframe, copybook, jrecord

I am trying to read mainframe file but all are working other than comp 3 file.Below program is giving strange values.It is not able to read the salary value which is double also it is  giving 2020202020.20 values. I don't know what am missing.Please help me to find it.

Program:

```
public final class Readcopybook {

    private String dataFile = "EMPFILE.txt";
    private String copybookName = "EMPCOPYBOOK.txt";

    public Readcopybook() {
        super();
        AbstractLine line;

        try {
            ICobolIOBuilder iob = JRecordInterface1.COBOL.newIOBuilder(copybookName)
                    .setFileOrganization(Constants.IO_BINARY_IBM_4680).setSplitCopybook(CopybookLoader.SPLIT_NONE);

            AbstractLineReader reader = iob.newReader(dataFile);
            while ((line = reader.read()) != null) {                
                System.out.println(line.getFieldValue("EMP-NO").asString() + " "
                        + line.getFieldValue("EMP-NAME").asString() + " " 
                        + line.getFieldValue("EMP-ADDRESS").asString() + " " 
                        + line.getFieldValue("EMP-SALARY").asString() + " "
                        + line.getFieldValue("EMP-ZIPCODE").asString());
            }

            reader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Readcopybook();
    }
}
```

**EMPCOPYBOOK:**

```
001700 01 EMP-RECORD.                                                           
001900        10  EMP-NO                     PIC 9(10).                         
002000        10  EMP-NAME                   PIC X(30).                         
002100        10  EMP-ADDRESS                PIC X(30).                         
002200        10  EMP-SALARY                 PIC S9(8)V9(2) COMP-3.             
002200        10  EMP-ZIPCODE                PIC 9(4).
```

**EMPFILE:**

```
0000001001suneel kumar r                bangalore                       e¡5671                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
0000001002JOSEPH                        WHITE FIELD                     rrn4500
```

**Output:**

```
1001 suneel kumar r bangalore 20200165a10 5671
   2020202020.20 
   2020202020.20 
   2020202020.20 
   2020202020.20 
   2020202020.20 
   2020202020.20 
   2020202020.20 
   2020202020.20 

  0.00 
1002 JOSEPH WHITE FIELD 202072726e0 4500
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem is you have done a **Ebcdic** to **Ascii** conversion on the file.
The 2020... is a dead give away x'20' is the ascii space character.
[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637188/unpacking-comp-3-digit-using-record-editor-jrecord/45645232#45645232) deals with problems with doing an **Ebcdic** to **ascii** conversion.

You need to do a **Binary** transfer from the Mainframe and read the file using Ebcdic. You will **need** to check the **RECFM** on the Mainframe. If the RECFM is

- **FB** - problems just transfer
- **VB** - either convert to FB on the mainframe of include the **RDW (Record Descriptor Word)** option in the transfer.
- **Other** - Convert to FB/VB on the mainframe

---

#### Updated java Code

```
int fileOrg = Constants.IO_FIXED_LENGTH_RECORDS; // or Constants.IO_VB
ICobolIOBuilder iob = JRecordInterface1.COBOL
        .newIOBuilder(copybookName)
             .setFileOrganization(fileOrg)
             .setFont("Cp037") 
             .setSplitCopybook(CopybookLoader.SPLIT_NONE);
```

---

**Note:** IO_BINARY_IBM_4680 is for [IBM 4690 Registers](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=ibm%204690&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=NdPAWZqLH8_r8AfBxZnIAw)

---

There is a wiki entry [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jrecord/wiki/Generate%20Code%20for%20Binary%20Cobol%20file/)

or this Question

[How do you generate java~jrecord code fror a Cobol copybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-fror-a-cobol-copybook)

Comment: Could you give me link or something from JRecord for this?