# How do you generate java~jrecord code for a Cobol copybook

Tags: java, cobol, mainframe, ebcdic, jrecord

How do you use the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) to *Generate* [Java~JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) code
from a *Cobol Copybook* to read/write a *Binary  EBCDIC Mainframe File*.

This a **Question** and **answer** to try an prevent some poor/misleading questions being asked or the answer can be pointed to.

Comment: Could you please add proper tags to the question, so that its open to a wider audience.

Comment: This is a Question I intend to Answer my-self. I want to cover the whole proccess. I will more tags later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### File Transfer

To transfer a **Binary** file from the Mainframe to Windows / *nix box you
must do a **Binary Transfer** for a very simple reason: the Ebcdic --> Ascii
program can not distinguish between binary fields and Text fields.

```
Comp-3 value   hex     hex after Ascii conversion

 400          x'400c'       x'200c'       x'40' is the ebcdic space character
                                          it gets converted to the ascii
                                          space character x'20'
```

You need to do a **Binary** transfer from the Mainframe. This will keep the file as EBCDIC and any binary fields will be untouched. You then read the file using Ebcdic.

You will **need** to check the **RECFM** on the Mainframe. If the **RECFM** is

- **FB** - no problems just transfer
- **VB** - either convert to FB on the mainframe of include the **RDW (Record Descriptor Word)** option in the file transfer.
- **Other** - Convert to FB/VB on the mainframe

### RecordEditor CodeGen

The [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) will use
details from a Cobol Copybook and a Sample file to generate Java~JRecord Code.

#### Installing the Recordeditor

Install version 0.98.4 or later. Consider the USB version, you just unzip to a normal directory and run from there. No install is needed

If you install either HSQL version, restart the computer before use

#### Starting the Code Generator

To start the Code-Generator, select **Generate >>> Java~JRecord code for Cobol**

[image]

#### First Generate Screen

On this screen enter the Cobol Copybook and Sample file (if you have one).
The **RecordEditor** will try and fill in the fields for you.

[image]

You may need to fix up the control fields though. When everything is correct

[image]

When everything is correct *press* the **Generate Java~JRecord** button

#### Second Generate Screen

On this screen you can

- Select the *Template* or *Model*
- How the Java names are formated
- package id etc.

[image]

#### Generated code

There are several *Templates* or *Models* that can be used, including

- **Standard** - generates basic JRecord code. It will generate Java classes with Cobol field names as constants. This allows you to use IDE code completion instead of typing in the "Cobol-Field-Names".
- **lineWrapper** - Create a Java Wrapper around the Cobol Data.
- **Pojo** - Creates Readers / Writers to convert Cobol Data to/from Java Pojo's

press the **Generate Code** button to generate java code.

**LineWrapper:**

[image]

**Pojo:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

RecordEditor portable wants to use Java 1.6.