# How to convert Java object to binary file using copybook

Tags: java, mainframe, copybook, jrecord

Is anyone aware of how to convert a Java object into a binary file using a COBOL copybook? The file is to be transmitted to mainframe and hence has to have the mapping with copybook. I tried looking at JRecord but I could find just the conversion from mainframe binary file into java object and not the other way round.
Can someone please help with it.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-fror-a-cobol-copybook. It shows you how to generate Java~JRecord code to read / write cobol data files

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at question [How do you generate java~jrecord code fror a Cobol copybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-fror-a-cobol-copybook) . It demonstrated how the use the [Recordeditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/files) to generate Java / JRecord code to read / write a file.

but broadly

```
    IIOBuilder ioBldr = JRecordInterface1.SCHEMA_XML .newIOBuilder(copybookName);


        try {
            AbstractLine saleRecord = ioBldr.newLine();
            AbstractLineWriter writer  = ioBldr.newWriter(salesFileOut);

            saleRecord.getFieldValue("KEYCODE-NO").set(1331);
            saleRecord.getFieldValue("STORE-NO").set(1);
            saleRecord.getFieldValue("DATE").set(80921);
            saleRecord.getFieldValue("DEPT-NO").set(100);
            saleRecord.getFieldValue("QTY-SOLD").set(7);
            saleRecord.getFieldValue("SALE-PRICE").set(7.00);
            writer.write(saleRecord);

            saleRecord.getFieldValue("STORE-NO").set(11);
            writer.write(saleRecord);

            saleRecord.getFieldValue("STORE-NO").set(121);
            writer.write(saleRecord);

            System.out.println(" " + saleRecord.getFieldValue("SALE-PRICE").asString());
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
```

While this uses an Xml-Schema; the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks which was helpful!