# Unable to unpack comp 3 to numeric in java

Tags: java, packed-decimal, comp-3

I referred a code on the internet to unpack comp 3 to numeric in java. I tried to pass a sample comp3 file to the code but I didn't get the proper unpacked data. I got some weird numbers. I am new to this concept(comp 3) so can you guys help me on this. Thanks in advance

**Below is my code**

---

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

/**
 * Converts between integer and an array of bytes in IBM mainframe packed
 * decimal format. The number of bytes required to store an integer is (digits +
 * 1) / 2. For example, a 7 digit number can be stored in 4 bytes. Each pair of
 * digits is packed into the two nibbles of one byte. The last nibble contains
 * the sign, 0F for positive and 0C for negative. For example 7654321 becomes
 * 0x76 0x54 0x32 0x1F.
 * 
 * This class is immutable. Once constructed you can extract the value as an
 * int, an array of bytes but you cannot change the value. Someone should
 * implement equals() and hashcode() to make this thing truly useful.
 */

public class PackedDecimalToComp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // test.unpackData(" 0x12345s");
            Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\AV00499269\\Desktop\\Comp3 data file\\Comp3Test.txt");
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            PackedDecimalToComp test = new PackedDecimalToComp();
            test.unpackData(data);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception is :" + ex.getMessage());
        }    
    }

    private static String unpackData(byte[] packedData) {
        String unpackedData = "";

        final int negativeSign = 13;
        for (int currentCharIndex = 0; currentCharIndex < packedData.length; currentCharIndex++) {
            byte firstDigit = (byte) ((packedData[currentCharIndex] >>> 4) & 0x0F);
            byte secondDigit = (byte) (packedData[currentCharIndex] & 0x0F);
            unpackedData += String.valueOf(firstDigit);
            if (currentCharIndex == (packedData.length - 1)) {
                if (secondDigit == negativeSign) {
                    unpackedData = "-" + unpackedData;
                }
            } else {
                unpackedData += String.valueOf(secondDigit);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Unpackeddata is :" + unpackedData);

        return unpackedData;
    }    
}
```

---

Comp3 file I passed has values `x019F`

When converted I got the unpacked data as `783031394`

Comment: The method `unpackData` looks to be working; your problem is elsewhere. Check the file in the **RecordEditor** (https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) to make sure that is correct

Comment: @BruceMartin when i unpack the comp 3 field value x019F I should get the unpacked data as 19 right? Since I am new to comp3 I have this doubt and can you explain me the logic used here in the above code. I don't have much clarity on that

Comment: @BruceMartin is there any alternate editor available for RecordEditor because my organisation doesn't allow to install RecordEditor

Comment: Use a hex editor then

Comment: The problem is you have the **ascii string` x019F = x'7830313946'** hex in your file. You need to put **binary 019F** in the file. The easiest way is to write it with a java program

Comment: @BruceMartin I put 019F in the file but the output i got was "3058324"

Comment: Yes you put the **character string** 019F in the file you need to put the **hex** string x'019F' in the file. Either use a **hex editor** or write a java program that writes 2 bytes 0x01 and 0x9F to a FileOutputStream. **Do not** use a text editor to create the file. Comp-3 is a **binary** type

Comment: Thanks @BruceMartin, could you tell me what is the comp 3 value of decimal number 19? I just want to know how the value will be.

Comment: The first byte will be 0x01, the second byte will be one of 0x9F - *unsigned comp-3* or 0x9C *signed comp-3*

Comment: @BruceMartin Do you have any java code which can convert comp 3 value (0x01 0x9F) to numeric (19) because I don't understand the code which i have mentioned above

Comment: Note that a packed decimal negative sign code can be X’B’ (11), or X‘D‘ (13). Both values are accepted as input to packed decimal instructions. Similarly, X‘A‘, X‘C‘, X‘E‘, and X‘F‘ all represent valus positive sign codes.

Comment: I was playing around with the code and it seems to be working as you'd expect ... can you give an example of the file and a hexdump of what isn't working ?

Comment: Hi @Hogstrom I need to write a basic java class which converts a comp 3 field value to numeric value . Ex: I need to convert 0x01 0x9F(comp3) to 19(numeric). If you have any sample code, can you share me. I dont understand the code which is available in the internet(mentioned above) and i am new to COBOL

Comment: @phunsoft I have a doubt if we unpack the comp-3 value say(0x01 0x9F), what will be the unpacked value, I mean in which format the value will be. Based on the code I mentioned can you say in which format the result unpacked data would be. Thanks in advance

Comment: @phunsoft from what I can see your code is working.  it reads the data and calculates how you'd expect ... if you have an example of the file your trying to convert that would be helpful

Comment: @Hogstrom I have a doubt can you tell me if I unpack a comp 3 value say 0x01 0x9F will I get the numeric value 19 or some other value in different format, because I tried that with the code mentioned above but I got some random number, can you help on that

Comment: @Hogstrom I have a mainframe file which is in ascii, in that there are comp 3 digits in certain field positions. How can i convert that ascii to comp3 and then unpack those comp3 field values. Can you help on this?

Comment: Comp-3 is really a binary format.  In COBOL you can have multiple data types include COMP, COMP-3, CHAR, ... it sounds like you have a file that has a mix of data types.  CHAR could be converted to ASCII / UTF-8, etc.  The Comp-3 is binary so you'd need to know the offset and length of those data elements.  I'm not sure I understand if you have a file that has multiple data types or not.  @BruceMartin's answer below is probably your best bet if your dealing with complex copybooks.

Comment: Yeah okay @Hogstrom

Comment: @BruceMartin I have a doubt. I have a mainframe file which is in ebcdic format. To Convert that to numeric should I have to convert the ebcdic file to binary. Because I dont understand the file. Its totally greek and latin for me

Comment: @Hogstrom  I have a doubt. I have a mainframe file which is in ebcdic format. To Convert that to numeric should I have to convert the ebcdic file to binary. Because I dont understand the file. Its totally greek and latin for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [IBM Record Generator for Java](https://developer.ibm.com/mainframe/products/record-generator-for-java/), a free tool.

This allows you to generate a Java class that represents a COBOL or PL/I DSECT which you can then use in your own code to read/write values to most COBOL and PL/I data types.  If you aren't working with a structure then you can see through the code how the underlying [JZOS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.80.doc/com.ibm.jzos/index.html) classes are used to interact with the datatype.

Although the tool is free it is supported by IBM, so if you hit an issue you can raise a problem with IBM and they will fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this @Will Yates

Comment: I have a doubt. I have a mainframe file which is in ebcdic format. To Convert that to numeric should I have to convert the ebcdic file to binary. Because I dont understand the file. Its totally greek and latin for me

Answer (score 0):

### Handling Mainframe binary file

You have 2 options:

- Convert the file to a Text file on the mainframe and then transfer the file
- Do a binary transfer and keep the file as EBCDIC then use something like JRecord to read the file. You can also use RecordEditor to edit the file

I have also seen files converted to Unix EBCDIC Text files on the mainframe and a binary Transfer (keep as EBCDIC). This is done for non-English EBCDIC where you have special language specific characters. Java editors (e.g. JEdit) have no trouble editing Unix Ebcdic files

### File Transfer (Mainframe)

To transfer a **Binary** file (has comp, comp-3 etc) from the Mainframe to
Windows / *nix box you must do a **Binary Transfer** for a very simple reason: the Ebcdic --> Ascii program can not distinguish between binary fields and Text fields.

```
Comp-3 value   hex     hex after Ascii conversion

 400          x'400c'       x'200c'       x'40' is the ebcdic space character
                                          it gets converted to the ascii
                                          space character x'20'
```

You need to do a **Binary** transfer from the Mainframe. This will keep the file as EBCDIC and any binary fields will be untouched. You then read the file using Ebcdic.

You will **need** to check the **RECFM** on the Mainframe. If the **RECFM** is

- **FB** - no problems just transfer
- **VB** - either convert to FB on the mainframe of include the **RDW (Record Descriptor Word)** option in the file transfer.
- **Other** - Convert to FB/VB on the mainframe

#### RecordEditor

- Make sure you have **Java** installed
- You can get the RecordEditor from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/files/Test/Version_0.99.0_Trial5/). You can either download an installer or the USB version. The USB version is a zipped Directory which you can install in any normal directory.

#### Using The Record Editor

You need to define the **Record Layout** (or file schema). The easiest way is to import a Cobol Copybook.

For a 2 byte comp-3 field, create a cobol copybook with

```
        01  Tst-Record.
            03  comp3-field              pic s9(3) comp-3.
```

To import the cobol copybook Select **Record Layouts >>> Load Cobol Copybook**

[image: Cobol import]

Then enter the **Cobol copybook file name** and press the **load Cobol** button at  the bottom of the screen

[image]

Next go the file open screen  and enter the file name and select the copybook you have just imported:

[image]

Hit enter and you should be able update the file:

[image]

#### Generating Code

The **RecordEditor** can also generate code for the [JRecord Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/). See [How do you generate java~jrecord code for a Cobol copybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-for-a-cobol-copybook) for hot to generate Java~JRecord Code using a Cobol Copybook.

You can also generate Code that does not use a Cobol Copybook wile editting the file:

Select **Generate >>> Generate Code from the File** option. Thene select a template and enter a package Id

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bruce Martin I will try this and get back to you

Comment: I have a doubt. I have a mainframe file which is in ebcdic format. To Convert that to numeric should I have to convert the ebcdic file to binary. Because I dont understand the file. Its totally greek and latin for me

Comment: By binary I mean **no translation** keep it in the mainframe ebcdic format

Comment: the file looks something like this " Áöðöóóðððùõøùõõ" " , how do I convert this to numeric. I don't have the mainframe file in binary format. Hopy you understand @Bruce Martin

Comment: If you have any approach to proceed further do share with me @Bruce Martin

Comment: Yes @Bruce Martin

Comment: 03 :XX:-SACH-ASHRAI     PIC S9(15) COMP-3.                 00001470
             03 :XX:-SEMEL-MAS       PIC 9(1).                          00001480
             03 :XX:-SEMEL-DMEI-NIHUL                                   00001490

Comment: I couldnt send the whole copy book so i sent a small portion of it

Comment: Just clarify onething, the mainframe file(ebcdic) has characters like this--> Áöðöóóðððùõøùõõ ..How can i unpack this to numeric? My doubt is can we convert the ebcdic to binary and then do further conversion(unpacking)?

Comment: Have a read of this answer. Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-for-a-cobol-copybook