# read S9(07)V99 COMP-3, S9(4) COMP-4, S9(3) COMP-3 values from text file in java

Tags: java, cobol

i have downloaded a text file from Mainframe which contains S9(07)V99 COMP-3, S9(4) COMP-4, S9(3), COMP-3 value in text file, how to read actual value of it in java.

Comment: Can you give us examples of these values?

Comment: Looks like this is related to cobol. You're not making it easy for anyone to help you...

Comment: The formats  of `COMP` and `COMP-n` data are system-specific, so it would help to know what system wrote the data.  On IBM mainframes,  `COMP-3` is packed-decimal and `COMP-4` is 2s-complement binary integer, but they could be just about anything on a different platform.  And you say this is **text file** you're dealing with?

Comment: The best solution would be to create a new file without `COMP-3` or `COMP-4` in COBOL and read this file into your JAVA program.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 basic directions for a file like this

- Convert comp-(n) fields to Text Fields on the mainframe (the sort utility is a good option) and do standard EBCDIC to ASCII transfer / translate.
- Do a binary (no EBCDIC Translation) transfer. You will have to handle

  - Mainframe file Structures yourself (they are different to PC / Unix strucutures)
  - Translate Ebcdic to Java-Unicode (For US Ebcdic, the encoding is CP037 (or IBM037)
  - Translate the Comp-(n) variables
  - The [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) can Read mainframe files in java using a Cobol Copybook. It can also handle mainframe file Structures

Either way you will probably have to do **another** file Transfer.
If you edit your transferred file with notepad an **can read** some of the Text,
the file is **corrupt**.

#### Why Transfer binary Mainframe files as EBCDIC

When converting an EBCDIC file to ASCII, the conversion program will
try and convert **every byte**, including binary fields.

Consider a comp-3 field with a value of 400

```
  Hex Represention   Hex representation after translation to ASCII
  
  
    40 0c               20 0c
```

in this case the EBCDIC space character (x'40') has been translated to
the ASCII space character (x'20') and 400 is now 200.

#### Mainframe File Structures

The 2 most common file structures on the Mainframe are

- Fixed Width files (RECFM=FB) -  where every  *record* (line) is a fixed length
- Variable Record Length files (RECFM=FB)  -  where every  *record* (line) is
  preceded by the length (RDW -record descriptor word).

#### RecordEditor / JRecord

[JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) will let you read the
mainframe file using a Cobol copybook. It can do the translation and handle
mainframe file structures.

The **Generate** option of the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) can create skelton
code to read a mainframe Cobol file from a sample file and Cobol Copybook.

Also see [How do you generate java~jrecord code for a Cobol copybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-for-a-cobol-copybook).

Comment: Is there any guide or steps how to use sort utility on the mainframe to convert comp-(n) fields to Text Fields

Comment: There are several manuals suitably constructed with Contents and Index pages, freely available and easily searched for. But why not ask the person/team who sent you the data in the first place to do the conversion and re-send?