# How do you edit a Binary Mainframe file in the RecordEditor using a Cobol Copybook (pt1)

Tags: record, binaryfiles, cobol, mainframe, copybook

How do you edit a *Single-Record-type* Binary Mainframe file in the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) using Cobol Copybook on a Windows or Linux PC.

**Note:** This is an attempt to split a very broad [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45729690/converting-comp-3-columns-in-mainframes-to-readable-format-using-record-editor-t/45780399#45780399) into a series of simpler Question and Answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Edit a File in the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) with a Cobol Copybook you must first load the copybook and then edit the file

#### Loading the Cobol Copybook into the **RecordEditor**

Select **Record Layouts >>> Load Cobol Copybook** menu options

[image]

[image]

On the Cobol Load Screen enter the *Cobol Copybook* and your *Mainframe Data file*.
The **RecordEditor** will read the file and try and work out what the *file attributes*
are.

[image]

The Important attributes

- **Split Copybook**: use *No Split* for a Single record type file
- **Font** (or Charset / encoding) You need to enter the appropriate encoding for the file.
  Cp037 (or IBM037) is US-EBCDIC, CP273 (or (IBM273) is German EBCDIC.
- **Cobol Dialect**  Mainframe for IBM Mainframe cobol
- **File Structure** This corresponds RECFM attribute on the Mainframe.

  - use **Fixed Length Binary** for RECFM=FB
  - use **Mainframe VB (rdw based) Binary** for RECFM=VB

The **RecordEditor** will try  display the file using the current attributes on the Righthand side of the
screen. You can play around with attribute.

[image]

If you can not get the file display correctly, you could have the **wrong** Cobol Copybook.
You must use a *Cobol Copybook* that matches the data exactly, near enough is **never** good enough.

---

#### Viewing (Editting your file)

Once you have loaded you copybook, go to the Open files screen.

....

- Select you data file
- select you copybook in the **Record Layout** field
- Click on on **Edit** (The **return** key should also work).

---

#### Generating Java Code to Read the file.

To generate *Java~JRecord* Code to read the file select **Generate >>> Generate Java~JRecord code for Cobol**.

The first screen is basically the same as the **Import Cobol Copybook** screen. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529152/how-do-i-identify-the-level-of-a-field-in-copybook-using-jrecord-in-java/45529902#45529902) has details on generating Java code