# EBCDIC to ASCII Conversions

Tags: python, unix, ascii, mainframe, ebcdic

I have mainframe file in EBCDIC format and I want to convert those files into ASCII format.

I have tried converting EBCDIC to ASCII using python 2.6 but there are many issues in that like compression field didn't get converted  and records count gets increased.

Is there any way to convert EBCDIC files having compressed fields to ASCII format.

Comment: If it contains packed or binary fields it isn't what I would call an EBCDIC-file. Your best bets would be: 1.) process it "as is" on the unix-side with proper handling of the record-layout and encoding or 2.) convert it to a pure EBCDIC-file (without packed or binary fields) on the mainframe-side, then convert it to ASCII.

Comment: It's doesn't contain packed or binary fields, it's pure mainframe file and I'm not sure how to proceed further

Comment: Well, what's that thing you call "compression field"?

Comment: In copybook it's length is mentioned as PIC S999V99 [COMP-3].

Comment: That is  packed decimal field

Comment: This field is not getting converted correctly while I'm doing with python 2.6

Comment: As Bruce Martin said, `COMP-3` is a "packed decimal" (or short "packed") field - any records containing this datatype will be totally destroyed by any type of EBCDIC->ASCII-conversions (if it is not aware of the record-format as defined in the copybook).

Comment: So there ain't any way to convert those packed decimal Fields correctly while converting EBCDIC -> ASCII?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the file downloaded you can convert it easily from EBCDIC to ASCII in a Linux or MacOS machine by using the command line.
To accomplish that you need to use the `dd` command.

Here a quick overview of some parameters it uses:

`dd [bs=size] [cbs=size] [conv=conversion] [count=n] [ibs=size] [if=file] [imsg=string] [iseek=n] [obs=s] [of=file] [omsg=string] [seek=n] [skip=n]`

There are more parameters that those above, to check all available just do the command: `man dd`, it will show all other available parameters and the explanation of each one.

In your case you should start with:

```
dd conv=ascii if=EBCDIC_file.txt of=ASCII_file.txt
```

where EBCDIC_file.txt is the filename of your input EBCDIC file and ASCII_file.txt will be the file created as output with all bytes converted from EBCDIC to ASCII.

Likewise you can do the reverse by using `conv=ebcdic` to convert a file from ASCII to EBCDIC.

Here's the man page for `dd` on the web: https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html

When you mention compressed in your file, do you mean the whole file comes compressed from the mainframe?  Probably it came TERSED (by using terse utility on mainframe). If this is the case, there is a public version of terse that runs on DOS, Linux, MacOS, AIX and others. It is available on cbtape site: http://www.cbttape.org/ftp/cbt/CBT892.zip

Answer (score 1):

### Options

Some options

- Convert the file to a Text file on the mainframe (sort or eastrieve will both do this)
- If it is a once off the Fileaid/File master can convert the file to Text on the mainframe
- If it is a once off the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) should be able to edit the file with a Cobol Copybook. It can also generate JRecord code to read the file.
- If there is only one Record-Type in the file, [CobolToCsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/) can use the Cobol Copybook to convert the file to a CSV.
- The [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) lets you read a Cobol Copybook in Java
- [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) has a COBOL Copy utility will let you do a Cobol to cobol copy. If there is only one Record type you can

  - Copy the EBCDIC Copybook to the equivalent Ascii copybook (ext fields are converted, binary fields are left unchanged). This is usefull if converting a Mainframe Cobol file for use in a Windows / Linux Cobol system
  - Copy a EBCDIC Binary Copybook to an Ascii Text copybook
- The [Stingray project](http://stingrayreader.sourceforge.net/cobol.html) provides access to cobol files in python

#### CobolTCsv

For Example to convert a Cobol Data File to Csv (single record type) using  [CobolToCsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/) :

```
java -jar ../lib/Cobol2Csv.jar -I In/DTAR020.bin  -O Out/o_DTAR020_space.csv ^
         -C DTAR020.cbl  ^
         -Q DoubleQuote  -FS Fixed_Length    ^
         -IC CP037 -Delimiter ,
```

Where

- **In/DTAR020.bin** is the Input Cobol data file
- **Out/o_DTAR020_space.csv** is the output Csv file
- **DTAR020.cbl ** is the Cobol Copybook
- **Fixed_Length** idicates it a fixed length File (FB on the Mainframe)

#### RecordEditor

- To edit the file see [How do you edit a Binary Mainframe file in the RecordEditor using a Cobol Copybook (pt1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794642/how-do-you-edit-a-binary-mainframe-file-in-the-recordeditor-using-a-cobol-copybo)
- To generate JRecord Code see [How do you generate java~jrecord code for a Cobol copybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-for-a-cobol-copybook)

Comment: Is there any other method like using Unix or Python?

Comment: In the answer I mention StingRay which is written in python also Cobol2Csv can be run in Unix (if you have java installed). The mainframe options (sort, eaytrieve) could be run under Mainframe~ZOs~Unix shell. MicroFocus probably has options that run under Unix but they would be expensive