# Convert EBCDIC data file to ASCII

Tags: ascii, cobol, data-files, ebcdic

I have an EBCDIC data file which is variable length.
Inside this file, it contains binary data (comp), packed-decimal (comp-3), display-numeric (pic (9)), and string (pic (x)).
How to convert it to ASCII using a language such as Java, Perl, or COBOL?

Comment: Hi @pat, i have similar task to do, did you get an Idea of how to do it?
that would help me.

Comment: You need a layout of the datafile. The only fields need to be changed are the strings and the display-numeric.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to verify that the file is still EBCDIC.  Some file transfer programs automatically convert the EBCDIC to ASCII, which corrupts the COMP and COMP-3 fields.  You can verify this visually by looking for space characters in the alphanumeric fields.  EBCDIC space is x'40'.  ASCII space is x'20'.

Assuming that the file is EBCDIC, you have to write three separate conversions.  COMP to ASCII, COMP-3 to ASCII, and alphanumeric to alphanumeric.  Each field in the record has to be extracted and converted separately.

The alphanumeric to alphanumeric conversion is basically a lookup table for the alphabet and digits.  You look up the EBCDIC character and replace it with an ASCII character.

COMP is a binary format.  It's usually 4 bytes or 8 bytes,

COMP-3 is a packed decimal format with a sign byte.  The sign byte is usually following the number, but not always.  For example, 124 looks like x'124F'.  The last byte is a sign field, x'C' is unsigned (positive), x'D' is negative, and x'F' is positive.

Comment: COMP may also be 2 bytes only.

Comment: COMP and COMP-3 are *binary* format, as you wrote, so why do you write they shall be converted to ASCII?

Comment: @phunsoft: Because I don't know which computer language the OP will be using to write the conversion code.  Once the numbers are ASCII strings, language specific code can be used to convert the ASCII numbers into numbers.

Comment: I don't agree. A COMP field holds a binary number, e.g. x'00000123', which in decimal is (1 x 256) + (2 x 16) + (3 x 1) = 291. You *cannot* converts this, except for a possibly needed big-endian to little-endian transformation. The same applies to COMP-3 or any other COMP-? field.

Comment: I think I only need to convert the strings (pic x) and zoned decimals (usage display), the comp and comp-3 are numeric and no need to convert.

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat each field by itself. You must not convert the COMP fields. You convert the character fields with the method provided by the language of choice.

Comment: If the target platform is little-endian, the COMP fields probably need conversion, just not to ASCII.

Comment: I think both comp and comp-3 do not need to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible (For java look at [JRecord](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) project). Jrecord can use a Cobol copybook to read a file in Java. It can also use a Xml description as well.

### Warnings

Before doing anything else

1. Make sure the file is **still Ebcdic** !!!. If the file has been through a EBCDIC to ASCII Conversion, the comp/comp-3 fields will be corrupted.
2. You describe the file as being variable length. Does that mean it has variable length records ???. If so make sure the **RDW option** was used to transfer the file !!

If you **do not** get the *file transfer** done **correctly** you will end up **wasting** a lot of time and then redoing what you have already done.

### Cobol Copybook

I am assuming you can get a Cobol copybook. If so

1. Try editing the file using the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/). There is an outdated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794642/how-do-you-edit-a-binary-mainframe-file-in-the-recordeditor-using-a-cobol-copybo). I will try and provide a more up to date answer.
2. You can generate Skelton Java/JRecord in the RecordEditor. See [How do you generate java~jrecord code for a Cobol copybook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313332/how-do-you-generate-javajrecord-code-for-a-cobol-copybook)

### JRecord Project

The JRecord project will read/write Cobol data files using

- A Cobol Copybook
- A Xml File Description
- File Schema defined in Java

There are 3 sub-project that can be used to convert **simple Cobol** files to
CSV, Xml or Json files. More complicated files need Java/JRecord

- [CobolToCsv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltocsv/)
- [CobolToXml](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltoxml/)
- [CobolToJson](https://sourceforge.net/projects/coboltojson/)

#### JRecord CodeGen

JRecord CodeGen will generate sample Java/JRecord code to Read/Write Cobol files (including Mainframe Cobol) from a Cobol Copybook. JRecord CodeGen is used by the [RecordEditor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/record-editor/) to generate Java/JRecord programs.